# Footnote and number in margin

Tags: footnotes, marginpar

I'm trying to make a footnote appear in the margin along with the footnote number. I can generate the footnote without number with a the command: `\newcommand{\marginfootnote}[1]{\marginpar{\footnotesize{#1}}\footnotemark}`. However, I can't seem to find a way to make the footnote number appear. Using `\footnotetext` makes the text disappear altogether (`\newcommand{\marginfootnote}[1]{\marginpar{\footnotetext{#1}}\footnotemark}`).

Here's a reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\marginfootnote}[1]{\marginpar{\footnotesize{#1}}\footnotemark}
\begin{document}
Can we put a footnote with number in the margin and a number in the text?\marginfootnote{There's no number here!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `marginnote` package.

Comment: Have a look at the `sidenotes` and `snotez` packages

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! I haven't been able to find a way around the issue with `marginnote`. @cgnieder, the `sidenotes`package seems to do exactly what I want too in addition to its other margin environments so I might end up using that. Thanks for the inputs both.

Comment: And actually ended up using `snotez` as it offers more options and is actively maintained. Good sugggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mgncount}
\renewcommand\themgncount{\arabic{mgncount} }
\newcommand\marginfootnote[1]{\refstepcounter{mgncount}\marginpar{{$^\themgncount$}#1}\footnotemark}
\begin{document}
Can we put a footnote with number in the margin and a number in the text?\marginfootnote{There's a number here!}

Another test\marginfootnote{Working!}

One more try\marginfootnote{Successful!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution does exactly what I needed! Instead of using math-mode, I found that `\textsuperscript{\themgncount}` keeps the font style, and then you can leave out the `\renencommand`-line. Thanks!

Comment: glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but the `memoir` class provides  "side footnotes" and many commands for controlling their appearance. See **12.5 Side Footnotes** in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`). You can see the code for this in `memoir.cls` and use what you think is appropriate for your needs.